# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a FATAL EXCEPTION with a NullPointerException  in line 275 of mainActivity ( Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());) I have referenced the object before  as JSONObject  json = new JSONObject(); and I'm still getting null pointer. My log cat  is below.

Log cat :

```
02-19 08:56:34.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1913): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-19 08:56:34.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1913): Process: com.example.newjudoapp, PID: 1913
02-19 08:56:34.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1913): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-19 08:56:34.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
02-19 08:56:34.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
02-19 08:56:34.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
02-19 08:56:34.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
02-19 08:56:34.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-19 08:56:34.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-19 08:56:34.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-19 08:56:34.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-19 08:56:34.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1913): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-19 08:56:34.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at com.example.newjudoapp.MainActivity$selectUser.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:275)
02-19 08:56:34.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at com.example.newjudoapp.MainActivity$selectUser.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
02-19 08:56:34.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-19 08:56:34.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-19 08:56:34.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: @Raghunandan  Log.d("Create Response", json.toString() )

Comment: Do a null check for your json if(null == json) then print json is null else your toast.

Comment: why didn't you post the code for hybridHTTPReuest? obviously it is what returns null, the issue is there.

Comment: @njzk2 i've added it now hope that will help

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are getting returned from...

```
json = jsonParser.hybridHTTPReuest(url, "POST", "GET", params);
```

...is `null`.

While you do instantiate a new instance, you then use it and set its value to `null` based on the return from the parser.

Comment: thanks for your help , I've added the hybridHTTPReuest and my jobj is getting deference I've tried many things but they all have failed , can you please help thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

please check what returning the "hybridHTTPReuest()" is null

Answer (score 0):

the `json` that u are passing to `Log.d("Create Response", json.toString() )` method is null, and the method requires string to print, check your `jsonParser.hybridHTTPReuest(url, "POST", "GET", params);` method whether its returning any value or not , meanwhile u can use `Log.d("Create Response", json.toString() +"")`

Comment: thanks for your help , I've added the hybridHTTPReuest and my jobj is getting deference do you know anyway to prevent this.